# How to get parent multiple levels up the DOM tree without jQuery or modifying Element.prototype?

Tags: javascript, dom, tree-traversal, dom-traversal

I am wondering if there is a way to select a specific element way up the DOM only using vanilla JS while not having to use `parentNode` multiple times. I understand you can do this with jQuery and modifying `Element.prototype`, but are there any other pretty ways to write this.

```js
  const deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.delete-button');

  for (var i = 0; i < deleteButtons.length; i++) {
    deleteButtons[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      //This is the crazy amount of parentNode usage
      bookDatabase.child(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("id")).remove();
      });
    }
```

Comment: You can use a for loop with a fixed number of iterations or use an id or class name to retrieve the element if possible.

Comment: You want a function that takes an element and a number and return the parent element at "number" of levels up?

Comment: These are great ideas, but I should have been more clear that I was looking for an existing method. Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is really only one other way, which is to use the DOM API [`element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), but it does require that you provide a selector that can uniquely identify the particular element you need (or the first element that matches that selector from the descendant's point of view). Without that, multiple uses of the `.parent()` method would be required and you'd need to know how many levels up you want to go.

```js
// Starting from the inner most level
var start = document.getElementById("source");

// Let's say you wanted to reference the first ancestor
// that has the "something3" class
start.closest(".something3").classList.add("red");

// Or, the second closest
var firstMatch = start.closest(".something2");
firstMatch.classList.add("yellow");

// Or, even higher
firstMatch.closest(".something1").classList.add("aqua");

// And, of course, you can skip levels
start.closest(".something1").classList.add("dropCap");
```

```css
#source {background-color:orange; }
.red { background-color:red; }
.yellow { background-color:yellow; font-size:1rem; }
.aqua { background-color:aqua; }
.dropCap { font-size:3em; }
```

```html
<div class="something1">Level 1
  <div class="something2">Level 2
    <div class="something3">Level 3
      <div id="source">Level 4</div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. I think I have seen element.closest() before, but I assumed it was jQuery. Good to know. Thank you.

Comment: This is looking good and neet. Its slove my issue. Big thanks

Answer (score 5):

**I ran into the same issue**... **This helped me a lot**

You can just traverse to the specific Parent Element you want by using

`element.closest('.parentClass')`  - or  - `element.closest('#parentId')`

Where  **'element'**  is the origin  element (in your case **'e.target'**), and

**'parentClass'** - or - **'parentID'** is the identifier of the parent Element you want.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the simplest way to get a parent node of a needed hierarchical level:

```
function getParentNode(element, level = 1) { // 1 - default value (if no 'level' parameter is passed to the function)
    while (level-- > 0) {
      element = element.parentNode;
      if (!element) return null; // to avoid a possible "TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null" if the requested level is higher than document
    }
    return element;
}
```

With this function, instead of:

```
e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode
```

you can use this:

```
getParentNode(e.target, 6)
```